Gitlab CI Pipeline ASP.NET Core. I cant execute docker-compose.yml
I can't execute docker-compose.yml, which is located in the repository. In the first job I'm calling docker-compose-test.yml, which is working successfully. In the second job I build a project and save the result as artefacts, then in the third job I'm creating a Dockerfile and publishing it (I'm not sure if it works the way I want it to). In the fourth job I'm trying to run my docker-compose.yml, but an error is displayed stating that the file was not found.
It is also noteworthy that during the execution of integration tests, the builds/username/name-project folder contains the project sources, including docker-compose. But on the last job this folder is already completely empty.
integrationstests:
  stage: test
  image: docker:24.0.5
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  services:
    - docker:24.0.5-dind
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add docker docker-compose
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose-tests.yml up --abort-on-container-exit --exit-code-from integrationtests

build:
    stage: build
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
    script:
        - dotnet restore Web/Web.csproj
        - dotnet build Web/Web.csproj -c Release --no-restore
        - dotnet publish Web/Web.csproj -c Release --no-build --output ./app
    artifacts:
        expire_in: 1 hour
        paths:
            - ./app/

publish:
    stage: publish
    image: docker:24.0.5
    services:
        - docker:24.0.5-dind
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
        DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
        DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    before_script:
        - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY    
        - |
            echo -e '
            FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
            WORKDIR /app
            COPY ./app .
            ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
            ' > Dockerfile
    script:
        - docker build --pull -f Dockerfile -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH .
        - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    dependencies:
        - build
    needs:
        - build

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    image: docker:24.0.5
    services:
        - docker:24.0.5-dind
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
        DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
        DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    before_script:
        - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    script:
        - apk update
        - apk add docker docker-compose
        - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
    dependencies:
        - publish
    needs:
        - publish

I was looking for a guide on how to set up a pipeline, but I couldn't find anything that could solve my problem.
